# Can't get the info to render correctly with accent characters

Tags: winforms, character-encoding

I have a webcall that gets the Ip information:

```
result = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://ip-api.com/csv/177.30.105.121?fields=status,countryCode,region,city,district,isp,proxy,query,message");
```

In my Winform application it displays in western not latin character set. Should show Goiânia

[image]

How can I get this decoded correctly to use the ISO-8859-1 character set.

From the comment, think I am getting closer but still didn't work.
[image]

Comment: `WebClient web = new WebClient(); web.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); web.DownloadString(...);` ?

Comment: that didn't work but seems logical

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case `'Goiânia'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'GoiÃ¢nia'`. The same for `…decode('iso-8859-1')` (example in Python).

Comment: Do you control the API? If so, the API response header states that the content is UTF-8 encoded, so just set the Encoding Property of your WebClient. Assuming the API content is actually UTF-8 encoded, since, in the Web Browser, the name you're referring to is returned as `Goiania`, not `Goiânia`. -- What is the Local Encoding here is irrelevant, strings are UTF-16LE encoded in .Net. As mentioned, just read the content as it's encoded by the API.

Comment: same result if I read it direct the string has those characters.Thats why I am messing with the encoding.

Comment: It looks like the API returns a JSON result with complete information, which includes the correct names of the locations, only when you use the API as intended, providing an Access Token. Then the resulting UTF-8 encoded JSON returns the expected values (including accents and other diacritics). When I use your code or a WebBrowser, as mentioned, I get back `Goiania`, not `Goiânia`. When I query the API, the resulting JSON contains `Goiânia`.